# SwiftUI: "Censored" / Marked Text Effect

Tags: text, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve a censored text look in SwiftUI. I've been placing a text and it's copy inside a `ZStack` and added a `.background(Color.black)` modifier to the front one. This works fine with single line texts. However, it doesn't look so good with multiline texts, as it results in a single black rectangle. Any ideas on how to achieve the look below with rather long, multiline texts?

[image: Censored Text Look]

For the sake of completeness, here's the simple code:

```
        HStack{
        Spacer()
            .frame(width: 50)
        
        ZStack {     
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et")
                .font(.system(.title2, design: .serif))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            
            
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et")
                .font(.system(.title2, design: .serif))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
```

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re targeting iOS 14, you could use the `redacted(reason:)` view modifier, which they added for widgets but works everywhere:

```
Text("View 0")
  .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was searching for! Thank you!

Comment: Not works correctly for center aligned texts